# Pygame holding down key

Tags: python

I am trying to make a fun program with a guy who opens his mouth whenever a press space. The problem is he only opens it for .1 seconds and then it closes again. I want to make it so that the mouth is open whenever i hold space.

Code:

```
    import pygame
pygame.init()

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Open The Mouth")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

faceImg = pygame.image.load("face_shut.png")
faceOpenImg = pygame.image.load("face_open.png")
def face(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(faceImg,(face_x,face_y))
def faceOpen(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(faceOpenImg,(faceOpen_x,faceOpen_y))

faceOpen_x = (1)
faceOpen_y = (1)

face_x = (1)
face_y = (1)

programRunning = True

while programRunning:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            programRunning = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                faceOpen(faceOpen_x,faceOpen_y)
                pygame.display.update()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                face(face_x,face_y)
                pygame.display.update()


    face(face_x,face_y)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: You appear to have the same code for "closing" its mouth (`face(face_x, face_y)`) directly after your `for` loop, but outside any if statements. Did you mean to do this? In other words, if this is your exact code starting at line 1, comment line 40.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue appears to be here:

```
while programRunning:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            programRunning = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                faceOpen(faceOpen_x,faceOpen_y)
                pygame.display.update()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                face(face_x,face_y)
                pygame.display.update()

    #  Here, always drawn closed at the end of the while
    face(face_x,face_y)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Regardless of what's being set in the while, you are redrawing the face as closed at the end.

How about this instead:

```
# Drawn before the loop starts
face(face_x,face_y)
pygame.display.update()

while programRunning:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        event_occurred = True
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            programRunning = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                faceOpen(faceOpen_x,faceOpen_y)
                pygame.display.update()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                face(face_x,face_y)
                pygame.display.update()

    clock.tick(60)
```